# Parse style attribute collection using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, projection

I want to parse an SVG style attribute, which is just a delimited string, e.g.

> "fill:#e2b126;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.3177;stroke-miterlimit:10"

into a `Dictionary<string,string>` so that I can perform some processing on it.

Here's what I have, which does the job, but I'd like to make it neater using a linq projection, just can't seem to get the syntax. I tried using .Select().ToDictionary etc, but no joy. Thanks:

```
string attributes = "fill:#e2b126;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.3177;stroke-miterlimit:10";
var pairs = attributes.Split(';').ToList();
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pairs.ForEach(p =>
    {
        var pair = p.Split(':');
        dic.Add(pair[0], pair[1]);
    });
 foreach (var k in dic.Keys)
 {
       Console.WriteLine(k + " " + dic[k]);
 }
```

Expected output:

```
fill #e2b126 
stroke #010101 
stroke-width 0.3177 
stroke-miterlimit 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
string attributes = "fill:#e2b126;stroke:#010101;stroke-width:0.3177;stroke-miterlimit:10";
var map = attributes
  .Split(new []{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(x => x.Split(new []{':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]);
```

Breakdown

The first `Split` call will return an array of `String` values where every entry is in the `key:value` format.  The following `Select` call will convert every one of those entries into a `string[]` where the first element is the key and the second is the value.  The `ToDictionary` call just expressly performs this mapping

Comment: Thanks - just what I was after, shame there is no overload of `.Split()` that takes a single `char`

Comment: @geedubb yes. it feels so natural that I often forget that it doesn't exist (hence my several edits of this answer :( )

Comment: Except that such a version *does* exist (assuming you don't care about `StringSplitOptions`): `"split me on spaces".Split(' ');` will work just fine (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @dlev good point, for cases like this though I tend to want to use `RemoveEmptyOptions` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @JaredPar I agree, was mostly being pedantic :) Honestly, I think the API designers decided that it was more important to have consistency in argument placement then to have a useable API (since of course the `params` parameter would need to be the last one, and heaven-forbid you specify your options before your delimiters...)

Comment: last line change to ` .ToDictionary(p => p[0].Trim(), p => p[1].Trim());` would be better.