# How to parse SVG styling properties using Linq (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, svg

I want to access [SVG styling properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties) with Linq. For SVG elements like ellipses I can simply check their attributes and get the corresponding values. Let's say my svg-file contains this ellipse:

```
<ellipse
     style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff60ff;stroke-width:0.47105053px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     id="path3338"
     cx="457.0145"
     cy="261.14557"
     rx="102.28526"
     ry="126.51072"
     transform="matrix(0.79195929,0.6105739,-0.6105739,0.79195929,0,0)" />
```

I use this code to get the information:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(PathToSvgFile);
IEnumerable<XElement> xmlEllipses = xml.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}ellipse");
SvgEllipse[] ellipses = (
                from data in xmlEllipses
                select new SvgEllipse
                {
                    Cx = data.Attribute("cx") != null 
                         ? (double)data.Attribute("cx") 
                         : 0,
                    Cy = data.Attribute("cy") != null 
                         ? (double)data.Attribute("cy") 
                         : 0,
                    Rx = data.Attribute("rx") != null
                         ? (double)data.Attribute("rx") 
                         : 0,
                    Ry = data.Attribute("ry") != null
                         ? (double)data.Attribute("ry") 
                         : 0
                }
                ).ToArray();
```

This piece of code selects all ellipse elements from the given svg-file and saves its attributes in my ellipse class.

I want to do the same thing for the style attribute of each element. The problem is, that the `value` of the `style` attribute is the whole style string:

> fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff60ff;stroke-width:0.47105053px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1

Currently I'm working on that string, using the `string.Split()` and `string.StartsWith()` functions to find the right properties and their values. It works, but I think it's unsafe and hard to read. Similar to this topic ([Parse style attribute collection using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740264/parse-style-attribute-collection-using-linq)).

Is there a possibility to handle the style attribute in an easy way, like shown above?

I hope my question is somehow clear. Thanks in advance!

A. Beginner

Comment: You need a CSS parser. This one is the first I found when I searched for such a thing. https://github.com/Athari/CsCss

Comment: Did you saw my answer?

Comment: @Alberto Yes I saw your answer and it looks very promising! I didn't have the time to test it though. But I will do it now and mark it as the correct answer if it works for me. :)

This is more fail safe than my approach, but still some string splitting. But I guess there is no way to do it with some kind of queries like the ellipse example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination with Split, Select, Tuple and a bit of Reflection to do that.

So, lets first convert style string in a List of Tuple

```
using System.Threading;

var styleValue = "fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ff60ff;stroke-width:0.47105053px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1";

Func<string, string> toTitleCase = s => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s).Replace("-","");

var styleValues = styleValue.Replace(" ", "")
                            .Split(new []{ ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(s => s.Split(':'))
                            .Select(s => Tuple.Create(toTitleCase(s[0]), s[1]))
                            .ToList();
```

The value of **styleValues** will be:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>>(7) 
{ 
    [(Fill, #ff0000)], 
    [(FillRule, evenodd)], 
    [(Stroke, #ff60ff)], 
    [(StrokeWidth, 0.47105053px)], 
    [(StrokeLinecap, butt)], 
    [(StrokeLinejoin, miter)], 
    [(StrokeOpacity, 1)] 
}
```

Assuming that you have a class that represent the style have those properties:

```
public class SvgStyle
{
    public string Fill { get; set; }
    public string FillRule { get; set; }
    public string Stroke { get; set; }
    public string StrokeWidth { get; set; }
    public string StrokeLinecap { get; set; }
    public string StrokeLinejoin { get; set; }
    public string StrokeOpacity { get; set; }
}
```

We can now use reflection to fill values in SvgStyle class

```
var svgStyle = new SvgStyle();

var svgStyleType = typeof(SvgStyle);

svgStyleType.GetProperties()
            .Join(styleValues, p => p.Name, sv => sv.Item1, (p,sv) => new { p, sv })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t => t.p.SetValue(svgStyle, t.sv.Item2));
```

Now your SvgStyle class will have all values

```
SvgStyle 
{
    Fill="#ff0000", 
    FillRule="evenodd", 
    Stroke="#ff60ff", 
    StrokeLinecap="butt", 
    StrokeLinejoin="miter", 
    StrokeOpacity="1", 
    StrokeWidth="0.47105053px" 
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works if my 'SvgStyle' class has all properties that might occur in my 'styleValues' List, otherwise I get an error. Let's say I just want to have specific properties, like 'Fill','Stroke' and 'StrokeWidth'. How do I have to modify your Code to check if my 'SvgStyle' class has implemented the current propertiy in my list and if not just move on?

I think this should be checked in the reflection line, right?

Sorry, but I've never heard of the reflection concept before, so I don't know how to fix it by myself.

Comment: @A.Beginner I fixed it. I was looking the list of key/value and looking for some property, now I reversed that, I get all properties, and look if there is any value in key/value that property name match with key

Comment: Thank you! This works better, but I still got errors in some cases. For example when there are unexpected blanks or a terminating semicolon at the end of the 'styleValue'. I altered the 'styleValues' assignment to deal with those problems and edited it in your post. Thank you very much for your help! Happy new year!

Comment: @A.Beginner Happy new Year you you too!!! I changed my answer with a little difference of what you proposed, you don't have to filter using string.IsNullOrEmpty, the Split method already can do that.

Comment: One more proposion. :)
If you use StringSplitOptions, you need to change `';'` to `new Char[] {';'}` or `new String[] {";"}`, right? At least I get an error otherwise.

Comment: @A.Beginner you can change this `new String[] {";"}` for this `new [] {";"}`